# Bootstrap4 navbar: how to right-align an icon and keep it out of the toggle?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to use the Twitter Bootstrap to layout my navbar so that there is "left", "middle" and "right" parts to it, where the middle part gets collapsed down under the `navbar-toggler` ("burger menu") when there's not enough space.

Codepen for a self-contained example: https://codepen.io/fiver/pen/eKJOMG

The part I have wrong (I think) is the definiton of the "icon" elements:

```
<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark ">
  <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">ExampleApp</a>
  <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button"
    data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-target="#navbarNav" >
    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"/>
  </button>

  <a className="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="#">Icon1</a>

  <div id="navbarNav" className="collapse navbar-collapse" >
    <ul className="navbar-nav">
      <li nav items></li>
      ....
    </ul>
  </div>

  <a className="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="#">Icon2</a>
</nav>
```

When there's enough horizontal space that the navbar-toggle is not needed, `Icon1` is in the wrong place:

[image: icon 1 in wrong place]

But when the `navbar-toggler` is active, and the menu is expanded, `Icon2` is in the wrong place:

[image]

At the moment, I'm only planning on having one of the `Icon` menu items in my app. I'm just using two here to illustrate the different behaviour when I put the icon in the two different places.

Note both placements seem to work the way I want when the `navbar-toggler` menu is active, but collapsed:

[image]

What do I need to do to make the icon act like `Icon2` when there's lots of space `navbar-toggler` and `Icon1` when space is constrained?

Answer (score 1):

- Use `d-flex` and `justify-content-between` for the `navbar-container`.
- Use  `w-100` for the `nav`
- Use `<a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="#">Icon1</a>` right after the `ExampleApp` anchor tag.
- Use `ml-auto` for the `navbar-toggler`
- Use `<a class="navbar-brand navbar-right pt-2" href="#">Icon2</a>` after the `nav`  tag.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div style="background-color: rgb(52, 58, 64);">
  <div id="navbar-container" class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark  w-100">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ExampleApp</a><a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="#">Icon1</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div id="navbarNav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Options</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Drop Item 1</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Drop Item 2</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Drop Item 3</a></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav><a class="navbar-brand navbar-right pt-2" href="#">Icon2</a></div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NzxqxW

## Update

If you want to align both of the `icons` on the right side, use this method.

- Use `d-flex` and `justify-content-between` for the `navbar-container`.
- Use  `w-100` for the `nav`
- Use `ml-auto` for the `navbar-toggler`.
- Create a new `d-flex justify-content-between` div outside of the `nav` for the two icons.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div style="background-color: rgb(52, 58, 64);">
  <div id="navbar-container" class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark  w-100">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ExampleApp</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div id="navbarNav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Options</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Drop Item 1</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Drop Item 2</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Drop Item 3</a></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between pt-2">
      <a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="#">Icon1</a>
      <a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="#">Icon2</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RJrxpL

Comment: This question has been marked as duplicate and I agree with that.  I will likely delete this question - you answer has value though, if you want to move your answer over to the indicated question, I will upvote it over there.

Comment: @Shorn Updated the answer. It is totally fine if you delete your question.  I will not waste my time anymore.

Comment: I'm not going to delete this question as per https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265737/924597 (though I did end up using the answer from that question because it's smaller).